# Slow SQLite Select Query

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am manipulating a big sqlite3 database and experiencing slow select queries. My goal is to load all the database into Python objects I created.

In short I do 46 "SELECT" queries in 0.5s, which is pretty slow to me (around 100 queries/s).

Basically, all my queries retrieves one row (checking the id) from a table. They look like that:

```
cursor_data.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE DATA_ID = {}".format(id))
```

I do `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at the beginning of the loops of queries. Not sure if that helps for "Select" queries, though.

Any idea?

Would retrieving all the row from the first table, then all the rows from the second one, and so on, be faster than retrieving one row from a table, then one row from another table, and looping until everything is loaded?

Many thanks!

Comment: How "big" is your sqlite database?  If performance is important, sqlite is usually the wrong tool.

Comment: 40MB, around 1M raws

Comment: So you're trying to read 1M rows, and it takes 0.5s?

Comment: No, it's 100 raws per second.

Comment: I edited my question for clarity

Comment: Your question says 100 queries/second

Comment: Thus the edit, it now says that one query = one raw

Comment: Why are you using a transaction for select queries?

Comment: If you're doing one query per row, you should expect it to be slow. That's just about the worst possible performance you can get from a select.

Comment: Show the table structure, and any indexes you have.

Comment: Unless there are data updates going on, wrapping a transaction around the queries is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I managed to solve my problem through several changes & optimizations, which I developed in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I managed to solve my problem, I will answers my questions:

- Yes 100 queries/second is slow
- Selecting one row at a time wasn't an efficient way of loading the entire database
- the queries `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `END TRANSACTION` have, indeed, nothing to do here and should be removed

What I have done:

- Load all the database first (query for all the tables) : `query = "Select * from TABLE"`
- Loop through all the queries' results to do the appropriate storage (Objects, arrays, w/e)
- Careful when indexing the resulting array of the queries. Doing things like `data = array[condition_on_array_col_1 & condition_on_array_col_2]` can take a huge time. If you know how the database is built, you can take advantage of that.